# File not being created/written in

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
org = "na"

OutputFile = open("F&FHOutput.txt", "a")

#Part 1
with open("input.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        string,letter = line.strip().split(",")
        print(string + "," + letter + "," + string.replace(letter, ""))
        OutputFile.write(string + "," + letter + "," + string.replace(letter, ""))


#Part 2
def remove_strings_recursive(lines):
    if not lines:
        return ""

    word,letter = lines[0].rstrip().split(',')

    org = word

    word = word.replace(letter, '')

    print(org + "," + letter + "," + word)

    OutputFile.write(org + "," + letter + "," + word)
 
    return word + '\n' + remove_strings_recursive(lines[1:])

    

with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

    result = remove_strings_recursive(lines)


OutputFile.close()
```

I am trying to have it take the same things that are being printed and put them into a new file that the program creates if the file doesn't exist. Every time I run the code, everything works fine but the output file is nowhere to be found. Could someone please help? (Sorry about the messy code)

Comment: code works when I run it

Comment: Do you get the file @Mick?

Comment: Probably because your file name has a special character `&` in it.

Comment: Yea, "F&FHOutput.txt" right?

Comment: yes, ill change it and see what happens

Comment: Thanks, it worked @kwkt, make it an answer so I can mark it answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file name has a special character (`&`), which can cause problems. Try changing the file name to a more standard one.